# How to get a list of objects from a stored procedure in EF Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a stored procedure that gets several parameters and based on them it calls another stored procedure.
The returning columns may vary based on the stored procedure that will be actually called.

So I built a base class that contains all the shared columns and extended it with different classes each with its own additional columns as models for the data to be returned from the stored procedures.

Here are the classes for example:

```
public class SP_BaseModel
{
    public decimal? Sum { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
}

public class SP_Extended1 : SP_BaseModel
{
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public string Hobby { get; set; }
}
```

I'm registering the above models in the DbContext like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<SP_BaseModel>().HasNoKey();
    modelBuilder.Entity<SP_Extended1>();
    ...
}
```

I've tried both of the following methods but neither works:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetData<T>(string param1, int? patam2 = null, DateTime? param3 = null) where T : SP_BaseModel
{
    return Context.Set<T>()
                  .FromSqlInterpolated($"EXEC SP_GetData {param1},{param2 ?? null},{param3 ?? null}");
}


public async Task<List<T>> GetData<T>(string param1, int? patam2 = null, DateTime? param3 = null) where T : SP_BaseModel
{
    return Context.Set<T>()
                  .FromSqlInterpolated($"EXEC SP_GetData {param1},{param2 ?? null},{param3 ?? null}").ToListAsync();
}
```

I'm creating a Nuget from that and in the client, I'm consuming it like this:

```
public List<SP_Extended1> GetData(DateTime? today = null)
{
    today ??= DateTime.Today;
    
    //This didn't work
    var list1 = unitOfWork.MyRepository.GetData<SP_Extended1>(...);
    
    //This didn't work as well
    var list2 = unitOfWork.GetData<SP_Extended1>(...).AsEnumerable();

    return ...
}
```

But I'm getting this error message:

```
'FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it.
Consider calling `AsEnumerable` after the FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated method to perform the composition on the client-side.'
```

Comment: `SP_GetData` Is Table Valued function? (Why EF Core users do not specify Database Engine)

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-user-defined-functions/sql-server-table-valued-functions/

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use inheritance here. Merge `SP_Extended1` with a base class. EF doesn't like inheritance classes. It usually takes a lot of blood to make it working. Easier to use independent classes. This is a sample:

I wrote the special class to get data from stored procedure

```
public class AccDef
{
    public string AccDefName { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }
    public string ZoneName { get; set; }
    public double? Quantity { get; set; }
    public double HaulawayAmount { get; set; }
    public double FuelAmount { get; set; }
    public double SumAmount { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string StrQuantity
    {
        get { return Quantity == null || Quantity == 0 ? "-" : string.Format("{0:F0}", Quantity); }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public string StrInvoiceDate
    {
        get { return InvoiceDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public string StrDeliveryDate
    {
        get { return DeliveryDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); }
    }
}
```

EF context

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<AccDef>(e =>
        {
            e.HasNoKey();
        });
```

This is my code to get data from the stored procedure using EF:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<AccDef>> GetAccDefReportDetailsData(DateTime endDate)
{
    var pEndDate = new SqlParameter("@EndDate", endDate);

    return await _context.Set<AccDef>()
             .FromSqlRaw("Execute sp_GetAccDefReportDetails  @EndDate", parameters: new[] { pEndDate })
            .ToArrayAsync();
}
```

After this I converted this array to list of my EF model entities.

Comment: The thing is, that I have about 20 different models that all have the same 15 fields and except for 3 that has an additional 2-3 fields. So duplicating the common 15 fields look like a pain. Are you sure there is no other way?

Comment: There is a way. You will  certainly find it if you google. I remember I was trying to do  it a year ago, but it was so complicated and so many things were needed to be configured that I decided that it will be much cheeper to copy paste several classes. Maybe you can convert data back to one base class after getting data from sp.

Comment: I created several speciall classes for sp only. Some SP returned several empty fields just for compatibilty. After this  I converted  these sp clases data back to my main model. You could think about using reflections for this.

Comment: Do you have a code sample to how I can get the data maybe in a data table or any other way then to a hard coded class object?

Comment: Yes, please check my edited answer and let me know if you need some more info

Comment: Thank you. Do you happen to know why can't I just have one big class and have the irrelevant columns be nulls? I tried it but it gave an error that an expected column is not present. Is there a way to mark the extended columns as optional?

Comment: You can try to mark them [NotMapped]  but I usually included empty values in select  query of stored procedure

Comment: NotMapped means they will never get values bit in my case the stored procedure may return them in somenof the cases.

Comment: Just add  fake fields in some SP for compatibility