# Execute procedure and return data from different tables in Net 5

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I am trying to run a procedure in a RESTful API with NET 5 and Entity Framework Core 5, the procedure returns data from different tables.

The problem I have is that I do not know how to execute the procedure to later return data, in the DetailsClientsDto class.

Try to run the procedure in the following ways, without success:

```
var result = await _context.Database.SqlQuery<DetailsClientsDto>("EXEC [dbo].[SPROC_DETAILS] @ID_USER", sqlParameters);

var result = await _context.SqlQuery<DetailsClientsDto>("EXEC [dbo].[SPROC_DETAILS] @ID_USER", sqlParameters);
```

The error:

```
DataBase facade does not contain a definition for SqlQuery. Is there a using directive missing?
```

The method I am using is:

```
private readonly MarketContext _context;
public ClientsRepository(MarketContext context) : base(context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public async Task<DetailsClientsDto> GetDetailsRepository(SearchDetailsDto details)
{
    var sqlParameters = new[]
    {
        new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "ID_USER",
            Value = details.IdUser,
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
        },
        new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "ID_CLIENT",
            Value = detalles.IdClient,
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
            IsNullable=true
        },
    };
    
    return await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var result = await _context.Database.SqlQuery<DetailsClientsDto>("EXEC [dbo].[SPROC_DETAILS] @ID_USER", sqlParameters);

        return result;
    }); 
}

public class DetailsClientsDto
{
    public int IdUser { get; set; }
    public int IdClient { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Adress { get; set; }
    public string Car { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

Please can you tell me how I should execute the procedure and return the data, thank you.

Comment: EF Core do nto have `SqlQuery` extension.

Comment: Thanks @SvyatoslavDanyliv. What would be the correct way to execute the procedure and return values ​​from several tables, without EFC?

Comment: I would suggest to install Dapper, otherwise you have to register DTO entities with EFCore Model.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thanks, where can I find an example to register the DTO entities with the EFCore model?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64469508/10646316)

Comment: See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations

Answer (score 0):

This is an example:

```
// Load this namespace to use SqlParameter
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

//.. or use db.Set<DetailsClientsDto>()
var result = await db.DetailsClientsDto 
  .FromSqlRaw("EXEC [dbo].[SPROC_DETAILS] @idUser, @anotherParam", 
    new SqlParameter("idUser", value1),     
    new SqlParameter("anotherParam", value2))
  .AsNoTracking()
  .ToListAsync()
```